# GoogleApiClient check for api availability on android

Tags: android, google-api-client

Is there a way to check for API availability when using the google api client upfront on calling connect?

Instead of

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder apiClientBuilder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context);
apiClientBuilder.addApi(API);
apiClientBuilder.addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
        ...
        } else {
            // handle missing api 
        }
                        }
                    });
GoogleApiClient client = apiClientBuilder.build();
client.connect();
```

I would like to use something like:

```
if (GoogleApiClient.isApiAvailable(API)) {
    GoogleApiClient.Builder apiClientBuilder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context);
    apiClientBuilder.addApi(API);
    GoogleApiClient client = apiClientBuilder.build();
    client.connect();
    ...
} else {
  // handle missing api without connecting
}
```

Comment: you can check `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable?`..on the device

Comment: In this concrete case I want to check for `Wearable.API`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29

Comment: @LordFlash , if google api services availble wearable is available too

Comment: @Vyacheslav, what if there is play services version, that still does not include some API? I.e. it's non-updated play services.

Comment: @azizbekian if i remember is case of wearable the connection will fail.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, assume I have play services version 2 on my device, and Awesome API appeared from play services version 3. Now, OP asks how to check that my device has Awesome API.  Will `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` help somehow?

Comment: @azizbekian good point..i think this will help: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability ..it is a Helper class for verifying that the Google Play services APK is available and up-to-date on this device.

Answer (score 2):

I have used code like the below to check for WearOS

```
    int result = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(ctx);
if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == result ) {

    MessageClient mc = Wearable.getMessageClient(ctx);

    try {
        Task<Void> t = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().checkApiAvailability(mc);

        t.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void v) {
                //... MessageClient available
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //.. MessageClient not available
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //.. MessageClient not available
    }
}
```